# How to answer the question "Are you legally authorized to work in the country where the job is located?"

Tags: discussion, jobs

I am a recent graduate from India and currently working in an analytics company as interaction designer.

Few days back I was filling the job application form for interaction designer post in yahoo (Job located in Paris) and I have encounter a section where I have to mention that if I am legally authorized to work in the country where the job is located. I am really confused what to fill in the box.

First of all, I don't have any visa for any country and secondly I don't have any criminal record (as I presumed by the question) so what should I do.

I have heard that after getting the acceptance from the company it provides you an offer letter which can be used as a leverage to get the visa. Is that true or do I need to apply for the visa first?

So I am rephrasing my question again:
**Question: If the job is open for international applicants then can I apply for the job if currently I don't have any legal right to work in job location? 
And If I can apply for the job then is it possible to get the legal rights to work in the job location?**

Comment: If you need to complete extra paper work compared to someone born in the country where the job is, you don't already have the legal right to work there.

Comment: Hi Random, thanks !
So by default I dont have legal rights to work in any country if I dont have green card or visa or any other document.

Am I right ? So do I need to answer it as "No, I dont legal right to work in this location"?. 

So I am extending my qustion here:
Question: If the job is open for internation applicants then can I apply for the job if currently I dont have any legal right to work in job location? 

And If I can apply for the job then is it possible to get the legal rights to work in the job location?

Comment: @Blyk That question is not one that Stack Exchange can answer.